# Mysql syntax error cannot figure out

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

I am new to mysql. (first thing I've really done) and can not figure out whats wrong with my syntax here:

```
INSERT INTO `nationz_clans` (verified, open, name, friendly_fire, registered, lastUsed, packedAllies, packedEnemies, packedMembers, description, balance) VALUES ( 1,'0,'testing',0,'1385263412958','1385263412958','','','','','0.0');
```

Error:

```
Error at SQL INSERT Query: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'testing',0,'1385263412958','1385263412958','','','','','0.0')' at line 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

a single quote after the zero?

Comment: Thanks! I honestly skimmed over that at least 20 times

Answer (score 1):

Remove this single quote:

```
...
VALUES ( 1,'0,'testing',0,'1385263412958','1385263412958','','','','','0.0');
           ^
```